# Why use the mmap function to create demand-zero areas of virtual memory with stdin?

Tags: c, linux

I saw a piece of code from a textbook that uses `mmap` to create a new virtual memory area as:

```
// void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);

bufp = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_ANON, 0, 0);
```

If the `MAP_ANON` flag bit is set, then the backing store is an anonymous object and the corresponding virtual pages are demand-zero.

But since the file descriptor is 0 (`stdin`), then what's the point to have it associated with anonymous file which is demand-zero? From my understanding, demand-zero is suitable for .bss section (uninitialised global variables), because those variables are 0 by default. But why map `stdin` as demand-zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading the man page of mmap().

At least on linux, when MAP_ANON is given, the file descriptor argument is ignored. Some implementations even require it to be -1. So the example is not actually mapping stdin.

This makes sense because an anonymous mapping is not backed by any file, i.e. it does not take the data from any file, so the file descriptor does not matter.

Comment: It would be good practice to use `-1` anyway, even if your implementation doesn't require it, so as to avoid precisely this sort of confusion.

Comment: Agreed. It would be best to use -1, especially since (according to the man page I read) some systems require it.

Comment: FYI such systems which require fd == -1 if MAP_ANON are the BSDs